# Java to SlackAPI message formatting error

Tags: java, spring, slack-api

Using Flip-table Library, I have created a formatted text table (see below):

```
╔════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╤════════════════════════════╗
║ #  │ S3 BUCKETNAME                                                   │ ENCRYPTION STATUS │ DATA CLASSIFICATION        ║
╠════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╪════════════════════════════╣
║ 1  │ bucket-1231231234                                               │ No                │ non-public                 ║
╟────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 2  │ bucket-12312312344574683576345743                               │ No                │ non-public                 ║
╟────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
║ 3  │ bucket-785748933898347593485934830498                           │ No                │ non-public                 ║
╟────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────────────────────╢
```

I want to send this to slack via api however the format keeps getting lost in translation. Code example to build message is below:

```
import allbegray.slack.SlackClientFactory;
import allbegray.slack.type.Attachment;
import allbegray.slack.type.Payload;
import allbegray.slack.webhook.SlackWebhookClient;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils;


   @Override
    public void sendSlackMessage(String text,String slackWebHook,String channel,String username) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(slackWebHook)) {
            SlackWebhookClient slackWebApiClient = SlackClientFactory
                .createWebhookClient(slackWebHook);
            Payload payload = new Payload();
            payload.setChannel(channel);
            payload.setUsername(username);
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.setText(text);
            attachment.setTitle("S3 Audit Results");
            payload.addAttachment(attachment);
            slackWebApiClient.post(payload);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to maybe post the message as a codeblock to keep the formatting?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BlockKit](https://api.slack.com/block-kit) and [mrkdwn](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting) to create a table and send it to the slack API like [this](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T02LG190Y3E#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22%60%60%60%20------------%20------------%20-----------%20%5Cn%7C%20Header%201%20%20%20%7C%20Header%202%20%20%20%7C%20Header%203%20%20%7C%5Cn%20============%20============%20===========%20%5Cn%7C%20body%20row%201%20%7C%20column%202%20%20%20%7C%20column%203%20%20%7C%5Cn%20------------%20------------%20-----------%20%60%60%60%22%7D%7D%5D%7D). Unfortunately, Slack does not have any easy native support for rendering tables

An easier alternative, it seems, would be to just send this data in a `csv` linked to a message.